# redux todomvc: what happens when new one item?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am learning [redux todomvc](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/85e2368ea9ff9b308fc873921ddf41929638f130/examples/todomvc), and have some questions about the source codes below. Any comments welcomed. Thanks.

Q1: why store.dispatch() and store.subscribe() not called? It seems that this example is a little different from the [data flow introduction](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncFlow.html) here.

Q2: can anyone explain what happens when new one item? How src/index.js, src/containers/App.js, src/components/Header.js, src/components/TodoTextInput.js work togother when new one item?

Q3: where are todos and actions from (src/containers/App.js)?

Q4: this state === store.getState() (in src/components/TodoTextInput.js)?

```
// src/index.js
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import App from './containers/App'
import reducer from './reducers'
import 'todomvc-app-css/index.css'

const store = createStore(reducer)

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)

// src/containers/App.js
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import MainSection from '../components/MainSection'
import * as TodoActions from '../actions'

const App = ({todos, actions}) => (//Q3: where are todos and actions from?
  <div>
    <Header addTodo={actions.addTodo} />  
    <MainSection todos={todos} actions={actions} />
  </div>
)

App.propTypes = {
  todos: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  todos: state.todos
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(TodoActions, dispatch)
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App)


// src/components/Header.js
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react'
import TodoTextInput from './TodoTextInput'

export default class Header extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    addTodo: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }

  handleSave = text => {
    if (text.length !== 0) {
      this.props.addTodo(text)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <header className="header">
        <h1>todos</h1>
        <TodoTextInput newTodo// where is it from?
                       onSave={this.handleSave}
                       placeholder="What needs to be done?" />
      </header>
    )
  }
}

// src/components/TodoTextInput.js
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import classnames from 'classnames'

export default class TodoTextInput extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    onSave: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    text: PropTypes.string,
    placeholder: PropTypes.string,
    editing: PropTypes.bool,
    newTodo: PropTypes.bool
  }

  state = {//Q4: this state === store.getState()?
    text: this.props.text || ''
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    const text = e.target.value.trim()
    if (e.which === 13) {
      this.props.onSave(text)
      if (this.props.newTodo) {
        this.setState({ text: '' })
      }
    }
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ text: e.target.value })
  }

  handleBlur = e => {
    if (!this.props.newTodo) {
      this.props.onSave(e.target.value)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input className={
        classnames({
          edit: this.props.editing,
          'new-todo': this.props.newTodo
        })}
        type="text"
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        autoFocus="true"
        value={this.state.text}
        onBlur={this.handleBlur}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onKeyDown={this.handleSubmit} />
    )
  }
}

// src/components/TodoItem.js
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import classnames from 'classnames'
import TodoTextInput from './TodoTextInput'

export default class TodoItem extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    todo: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    editTodo: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    deleteTodo: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    completeTodo: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }

  state = {
    editing: false
  }

  handleDoubleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ editing: true })
  }

  handleSave = (id, text) => {
    if (text.length === 0) {
      this.props.deleteTodo(id)
    } else {
      this.props.editTodo(id, text)
    }
    this.setState({ editing: false })
  }

  render() {
    const { todo, completeTodo, deleteTodo } = this.props

    let element
    if (this.state.editing) {
      element = (
        <TodoTextInput text={todo.text}
                       editing={this.state.editing}
                       onSave={(text) => this.handleSave(todo.id, text)} />
      )
    } else {
      element = (
        <div className="view">
          <input className="toggle"
                 type="checkbox"
                 checked={todo.completed}
                 onChange={() => completeTodo(todo.id)} />
          <label onDoubleClick={this.handleDoubleClick}>
            {todo.text}
          </label>
          <button className="destroy"
                  onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.id)} />
        </div>
      )
    }

    return (
      <li className={classnames({
        completed: todo.completed,
        editing: this.state.editing
      })}>
        {element}
      </li>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1 why store.dispatch() and store.subscribe() not called?

Because of 'container'. In redux, a container is a component that subscribes to changes in store. This is done with Redux's `mapStateToProps` ,`mapDispatchToProps` and finally the `connect` function calls inside the [container file](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/85e2368ea9ff9b308fc873921ddf41929638f130/examples/todomvc/src/containers/App.js#L20)

The `connect` function does call `store.subscribe` internally.

> Q2: can anyone explain what happens when new one item?

1. the `App` container pass on the `actions` prop to the `App` component via [`mapDispatchToProps`](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/85e2368ea9ff9b308fc873921ddf41929638f130/examples/todomvc/src/containers/App.js#L25)
2. This prop `actions` contains the action `addTodo` and that is past down to the [`Header`](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/85e2368ea9ff9b308fc873921ddf41929638f130/examples/todomvc/src/containers/App.js#L10)
3. The `Header` component call the `addTodo` action upon the `TextInput` is [saved](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/85e2368ea9ff9b308fc873921ddf41929638f130/examples/todomvc/src/components/Header.js#L11)
4. The action [`addTodo`](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/85e2368ea9ff9b308fc873921ddf41929638f130/examples/todomvc/src/actions/index.js#L3) is dispatched
5. The reducer [handles](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/85e2368ea9ff9b308fc873921ddf41929638f130/examples/todomvc/src/reducers/todos.js#L13) the action and update the state with new item. Store is updated.
6. Store update triggers the `App` container to rerender with updated props because the `App` container has [`mapStateToProps`](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/85e2368ea9ff9b308fc873921ddf41929638f130/examples/todomvc/src/containers/App.js#L20)
7. done

> Q3: where are todos and actions from (src/containers/App.js)?

Again this is because of the Redux's `connect` function. It will get the returned values from both `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`, merge them and pass it to the `App` component as props. `todos` comes from  `mapStateToProps` and `actions` is from `mapDispatchToProps`

> Q4 this state === store.getState()

Dont be confused. The `state` in the `TodoTextInput` is React's native component state and has nothing to do with Redux's state. However, if you need a state in your app, it is very common that one needs to decide if it  should live in a Redux store or in the component itself.

If the state is only relevant to the component itself and no other component needs to know the status of that state, it indicates that it should live inside the component instead of being in Redux's store.

The state in the `TodoTextInput` component holds user input temporary before user commits the change. It is well fit to be an internal state of the component itself.

Comment: Thanks. (Q1)  what is `Redux's state` in this example? Something similar to https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/85e2368ea9ff9b308fc873921ddf41929638f130/examples/todomvc/src/reducers/todos.js#L3? (Q2) What does `state` mean in `mapStateToProps`? Thanks

Comment: @BAE   (Q1) Redux's state is the one in a 'Store', i.e. those you define and modify with 'Reducers', yes, the link you put here refers to the initial state inside the 'Store'. Think about Redux's store is one big Javascript object holding all status of your app.  (Q2) the `state` in `mapStateToProps` still refer to the states in the Redux's 'Store'.

Comment: Q1, I still have some questions: Why `({todos, actions})` not `(todos, actions)` in https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/85e2368ea9ff9b308fc873921ddf41929638f130/examples/todomvc/src/containers/App.js#L8  ?

Q2, https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/85e2368ea9ff9b308fc873921ddf41929638f130/examples/todomvc/src/containers/App.js#L21
Q: what does `state` look like? Does it have a property called `todos`? Where defined?

Comment: Q3, https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/85e2368ea9ff9b308fc873921ddf41929638f130/examples/todomvc/src/reducers/todos.js
Q: Per my understanding, Redux's state is an Array. all the reducers should return an Array? Am I right?
Where are data stored?

Comment: Q1 @BAE   `{todos, actions}` is the syntax in ES6, it is called auto destruction, you can take the whole `{todos, actions}` as `props` object, that ES6, simply automatically creates two local variables for you  `todos=props.todos` and `actions=props.actions`.

Comment: Q2, to findout the structure of the Redux's state, you will need to look at the reducers. [here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/85e2368ea9ff9b308fc873921ddf41929638f130/examples/todomvc/src/reducers/index.js#L5) shows it is an object with `todos` props and [here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/85e2368ea9ff9b308fc873921ddf41929638f130/examples/todomvc/src/reducers/todos.js#L3) shows that `todos` is an array of objects

Comment: Q3, no that only shows a branch (`todos`) value is an Array ( of todo objects ). All reducer should return what the new state of the branch it is in charge of, it can be any thing. but in your example, it is an Array.  Redux's state is always an object as a whole.

Comment: Thanks. https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/85e2368ea9ff9b308fc873921ddf41929638f130/examples/todomvc/src/components/TodoTextInput.js#L28, this.setState() is used to set the state of each Component. Each element of the array (Redux's state) can be matched to the state of each Component? which function does this?

Comment: no, that `this.setState()` is for keeping the user input and making the text input a 'controlled' element. Has nothing to do with Redux. For your next question, I am not sure what  'matched to the state' means. Components just render according to the props it receives. You control this by setting the right props.